# paperclip-dropbox gem throws wrong argument type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to use the paperclip-dropbox gem [here](https://github.com/janko-m/paperclip-dropbox/blob/master/README.md), and I'm having issues with the setup and passing my credentials.

In the documentation, the setup in the model is done like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar,
   :storage => :dropbox,
   :dropbox_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/dropbox.yml",
   :dropbox_options => {...}
end
```

I have configured my dropbox.yml file and put in the /config folder but rails is telling me the file or directory doesn't exist.

If I pass my credentials in the hash with the environment variables,

```
:dropbox_credentials => {
                  app_key: ENV["DROPBOX_APP_KEY"],
                  app_secret: ENV["DROPBOX_APP_SECRET"],
                  access_token: ENV["DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN"],
                  access_token_secret: ENV["DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"],
                  user_id: ENV["DROPBOX_USER_ID"]
                }
:dropbox_options => {
                  :path => ":attachment/:id/:basename.:extension"
                }
```

The top of the stack trace is:

```
paperclip-dropbox (1.0.0) lib/paperclip/storage/dropbox.rb:59:in `path_for_url'
paperclip-dropbox (1.0.0) lib/paperclip/storage/dropbox.rb:55:in `path'
paperclip-dropbox (1.0.0) lib/paperclip/storage/dropbox.rb:41:in `exists?'
paperclip (3.2.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:436:in `block in queue_all_for_delete'
paperclip (3.2.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:435:in `map'
paperclip (3.2.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:435:in `queue_all_for_delete'
paperclip (3.2.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:213:in `clear'
paperclip (3.2.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:94:in `assign'
paperclip (3.2.0) lib/paperclip.rb:196:in `block in has_attached_file'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:85:in `block in       assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:212:in `block in   update_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in   with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.6)  lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in  `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:211:in `update_attributes'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:45:in `update'
```

then rails says "wrong argument type String expected Proc"

I'm new to ruby and don't quite understand procs. How do I fix this to get it to work?

Comment: What do you have in `:dropbox_options`?

Comment: Could you add the full stack trace of the error please?

Comment: @ZachKemp, I added the :dropbox_options hash and the stack trace. and after looking at the stack trace, I'm starting to think my problem is with with path that I'm trying to save to. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the readme, paperclip-dropbox expects a proc for the path. Does the `:avatar` parameter in your path mean anything, or is that meant to be a static portion?

I think you need to try something like this:

```
:path => proc { |style| "avatars/#{id}/#{style}/#{avatar.original_filename}" }
```

You also can try it without the `|style|` variable, but you might get a wrong number of arguments error. Typically, one would define additional styles to automatically scale images to the sizes you need on your site - have a look at the [docs](https://github.com/janko-m/paperclip-dropbox/blob/master/README.md) for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much. I configured it to work for what I need since I'm storing text files rather than images